# How to replace a specific integer with the smallest index in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list `[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 13, 20 ,13]`, and I want to make it into `[11, 12, 100, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 13, 20 ,13]` (to replace the 13 with smallest index by 100.)

My code is:

```
lst= [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 13, 20 ,13]
k='13 100'.split()
for i in range(len(lst)):
       if lst[i]== int(k[0]):
            lst[i]=int(k[1])
            break
```

It works, but I'd like to know another method which is more simple and able to shorten the execution time.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple as that:

```
lst= [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 13, 20, 13]
lst[lst.index(13)] = 100
```

Which produces

```
[11, 12, 100, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 13, 20, 13]
```

---

Now if you are not sure if `13` is contained in your list, you can wrap the above code in a `try-except` block:

```
try:
    lst[lst.index(13)] = 100
except ValueError:
    print('Value does not exist in list')
```

Comment: Cool! Since it stops after finding the first 13, so the latter ones will not be changed.

Comment: @ypsilon This happens due to the way `.index()` list method works. It only returns the first instance.

Comment: @ypsilon You could also replace the `k='13 100'.split()` and subsequent casts to `int` in every loop with `v_old, v_new = map(int, '13 100'.split())`

Answer (score 0):

```
sp_int = 13
replace_value=100
lst= [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 13, 20, 13]
if(sp_int in lst):
   lst[lst.index(sp_int)]=replace_value
```

Above program would solve your problem. "in" operator search for element and return s true if present else false. 
index function determines the index of specified integer in a list.